# Dangling pointer example

Tags: c++, dangling-pointer

In the following code, why does `s1.printVal` causes a dangling pointer error? Isn't the `s1` object, i.e. its pointer, still accessible until it's destroyed?

```
class Sample
{
  public:
    int *ptr;
    Sample(int i)
    {
        ptr = new int(i);
    }

    ~Sample()
    {
        delete ptr;
    }
    void PrintVal()
    {
        cout << "The value is " << *ptr;
    }
};

void SomeFunc(Sample x)
{
    cout << "Say i am in someFunc " << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Sample s1 = 10;
    SomeFunc(s1);
    s1.PrintVal(); // dangling pointer
}
```

[Source](http://www.techinterviews.com/c-object-oriented-questions)

Comment: Not a very "correct" example. It illustrates the dangling pointer problem and what the lack of copy ctor\copy assignment operator does to abstractions holding pointers to dynamically allocated memory but the implicit conversion from int just gives me the creeps.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem here is the **copy** that is done for argument of the `SomeFunc()`. That copy de-allocates your pointer when destroyed. You need to also implement a **copy constructor**, and **copy assignment operator**. See [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

#### Edit:

Here's "expanded" pseudo-code, i.e. what the compiler does for you in the `main()` function:

```
// main
addr0 = grab_stack_space( sizeof( Sample )); // alloc stack space for s1
Sample::ctor( addr0, 10 );                   // call ctor of Sample
addr1 = grab_stack_space( sizeof( Sample )); // alloc stack for argument
Sample::ctor( addr1, addr0 );                // call COPY-ctor of Sample
SomeFunc( addr1 );                           // call SomeFunc
Sample::dtor( addr1 );                       // XXX: destruct the copy
free_stack_space( addr1, sizeof( Sample ));  // free stack taken by copy
Sample::PrintVal( addr0 );                   // call member func on s1
Sample::dtor( addr0 );                       // destruct s1
free_stack_space( addr0, sizeof( Sample ));  // YYY: free stack taken by s1
```

This is *not the exact representation*, but a conceptual explanation. It just helps to think in terms of what compiler has to do with your code.

The pointer member of `Sample` is `delete`-ed at the step marked with `XXX`, and then `delete`-ed again at the step `YYY`.

Answer (score 3):

Nikolai's answer explains everything, but here is a possible alternative:

If you intend multiple instances of `Sample` to share the same underlying pointer, you may also use something like `boost::shared_ptr` instead of a raw pointer.

This has a little cost, but probably no more than if you try to do it yourself.

Moreover, this would avoid the need to write any of the copy constructor, destructor and assignement operator.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `SomeFunc(Sample x)`, the object `x` is created by calling `Sample`'s copy-constructor.  Since you didn't explicitly write one, the compiler creates an implicit one.  Normally, the implicit one is fine: It does a member-by-member copy (If you had used a `vector<int>` instead of an `int*` your code would have worked).  However, in this case, it's no good.  It just copies that value of `ptr`, so now, x.ptr & s1.ptr point to the same int[].  Now, when SomeFunc ends, `x` is destroy, and the destructor is called on it, meaning `ptr` is deleted.  That frees the memory used by `x`, but since it's the same value, it's also the memory used by `s1`.

Answer (score 1):

Nikolai's answer is absolutely right. As is ereOn's.

You also need to consider the difference between pass-by-value and pass-by-reference.

If SomeFunc was declared as:

`void SomeFunc(Sample& x)`

or even better

`void SomeFunc(const Sample& x)`

you would not have a dangling pointer problem.

The way you have defined `SomeFunc`, the `Sample` object is passed by value, which means a temporary copy is made for use within the scope of `SomeFunc`. Then, when `SomeFunc` returns the temporary object goes out of scope and its destructor gets called, which deletes the integer pointed to by `ptr`.

If you pass a reference to the `Sample` object, then no copies get made while calling `SomeFunc` and, hence, no destructor gets called when `SomeFunc` returns.